# counting using a while loop nesting a for loop

Tags: python, iteration

I'm trying to print a quick 'top 5 high scores' list, everything else in the program is fine but in the last section using while loop with a for loop inside it and incrementing count in the for loop, the count increments but the loop does not stop. I don't know why, can anyone explain it to me? or give me a fix please.

```
import csv

with open ('gradesfile.csv' , 'w', newline = '') as file: # creates csv
    writer = csv.writer(file) # creates a python object to work with
    writer.writerow (['Akki', 55])
    writer.writerow (['Edna', 78])
    writer.writerow (['Bob', 67])
    writer.writerow (['Eave', 22])
    writer.writerow (['Albert', 45])
    writer.writerow (['Enrique', 81])


yourname = input('enter your name:')
yourscore = 99


with open ('gradesfile.csv' , 'a', newline = '') as file: # add to csv file
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow ([yourname,yourscore])

# create the sort of this info and display to the user
# Create a list to catch the highscores
highscores =  []

with open ('gradesfile.csv','r') as hfile:
    for line in hfile:  # loop over every line
        line = line.strip('\n')
        sline = line.split(',')
        name  = sline [0]
        score = sline[1]
        highscores.append((score, name))
        
#print (highscores)

highscores.sort(reverse = True)
#print(highscores)
print ('\n')
print ('B.O.A.T LIST')

count= 0  # creates count
while count<5:  # conditional loop to stop at 5 prints
    for item in highscores:    #loops over the tuples in the highscores list
        count +=1  # increments the count
        print ('PLAYER NAME : ', item[0], 'SCORE : ', item [1]) 
        print (count)  # demonstrate count is incrementing
```

Comment: if `highscores` is empty your while loop will never stop.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? The ``count<5`` condition applies to the ``while`` loop, not the contained ``for`` loop. If you want to get only the "first 5 elements of ``highscores``", then slicing via ``highscores[:5]`` or ``itertools.isclice(highscores, 5)`` is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

This is because once the for loop started, the variable count has no scope to check the condition you provided in the while loop. This can be a solution:

```
count= 0
for item in highscores:    #loops over the tuples in the highscores list
    count +=1  # increments the count
    print ('PLAYER NAME : ', item[0], 'SCORE : ', item [1]) 
    if(count == 5)
        break
```

Comment: Please be aware that counting elements of a ``for``-loop is idiomatically done using ``enumerate``, instead of manually incrementing a counter. Even then, selecting "the first n elements" is more appropriately done using slicing, not counting.

Comment: Yes. I agree. But the person asked the question seems relatively new in python or coding. It is easier for anyone to interpret this code rather than using enumerate or slicing.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop doesn't necessarily have to stop when count >= 5. It depends on how many items there are in highscores.